# Avoid immediate executing of a function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function executed in a script

```
$(document).ready(documentReady);

function documentReady(){
      console.log("Ready");
      $(".loadMore").on("click",loadMoreClicked(this.id));
}

function loadMoreClicked(elementID){
//do something with elementID
}
```

However, everytime the document loads up, it executes **instantly** the `loadMoreClicked` function - thus giving an error.

It seems that if I just want to assign a function to the `click` event without it being executed directly, I have to remove any argument. 
Why does it happen, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the parentheses and the argument, `this` will be available in the callback

```
$(".loadMore").on("click", loadMoreClicked);

function loadMoreClicked(){
    var elementID = this.id;
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is also an option. I am sure you are aware, but if others are not, jQuery implicitly calls `.bind(this)` on callback functions, and as a result `this` will be the current clicked element in the `loadMoreClicked` function shown here.

Comment: I really dig this. But what if I need to pass a random argument into the function? It still executes it.

Comment: If you really need to pass random arguments in, you can use `bind` or an anonyomus function like in Travis answer, or `on` also accepts an optional `data` argument

Comment: Thanks! I'll take this as a model then.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an anonymous function to make the callback call

```
$(".loadMore").on("click",function(){ loadMoreClicked(this.id) });
```

Without this, the function is called immediately on document load causing the direct execution behavior you are observing. It will also assign the return value of the function (`undefined` in this case) to the click handler which is also undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.loadMore').click(function(event) {
        var self = $(this);
        var element = self.attr('id');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set an anonymous function as handler like this

```
function documentReady(){
      console.log("Ready");
      $(".loadMore").on("click",function(){
          var element = this.id;
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a good practice to delegate .off() before .on() to prevent multiple click event listener added to prevent memory leak. ie.

```
$(".loadMore").off("click").on("click",loadMoreClicked(this.id));
```

next, an [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) would prevent any default action and intercepted by your function.

```
$(".loadMore").off("click").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   loadMoreClicked(this.id);   
});
```

Hope this helps.